# ExternalLogin() in Asp.net MVC not passing changed viewmodel data correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

In my ASP.Net MVc site I have a Register action that takes my RegisterViewModel

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
       // register code here
    }
```

and I have the external login action "ExternalLogin" for sites like Facebook. Both of these actions were  part of the ASP.Net MVC template I used.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ExternalLogin(RegisterViewModel model, string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["gender"] = model.Gender;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["profileType"] = model.ProfileType;
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
    }
```

When I call "Register", my RegisterViewModel data is all good (model.Gender, model.ProfileType, etc.), but when I call "ExternalLogin" Gender and ProfileType aren't correct. They are the default values.

Anyone know why this is?

Here is the html and code in the viewmodel

```
<div id="formGroup1" class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Gender, new { @id = "genderLabel" })
            <div class="">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, new {@id = "genderId", @class = "selectpicker form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
<div id="formGroup2" class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProfileType, new { @id = "profileTypeLabel", @class = "" })
            <div class="">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.ProfileType, new { @class = "form-control selectpicker" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

in my viewmodel I have

```
    [Required()]
    [Display(Name = "I am a")]
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [Display(Name = "Who wants to")]
    public ProfileType ProfileType { get; set; }
```

Comment: Are there other items in your viewmodel besides Gender and ProfileType?

Answer (score 0):

Your CSHTML code is missing the essential parts which determine whether or not the data gets loaded into the view model, namely the **form and buttons**.

The data will only get loaded into the view model properly if the ASP input elements are specified within the same form as the button which redirects to your controller.

I am guessing in your scenario, the buttons associated to `Register` and `ExternalLogin` are located in two separate forms.

(I also presume you have `@model` set up correctly at the top of your page.)